# Executar comando em JS usando string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho um comando para pegar o tamanho do meu json, mas preciso usar uma string para indicar qual objeto quero pegar o tamanho:

```
var comando = data.result[0][0].'Pedidos'.length;
```

o erro que me da é esse:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string**

Comment: Ou tentou utilizar sem apóstrofos? data.result[0][0].pedidos.length ?

Comment: talvez você pode acessar como um datatable em c#. data.result[0]["Pedidos"].length;

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo desse JSON?

Comment: Essa string é fixa, ou está numa variável? Se for fixa, por que não fazer simplesmente `data.result[0][0].Pedidos.length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que seu `data` possui uma estrutura tipo:

```
{                                 // data
    "result":[                    // data.result
        [                         // data.result[0]
            {                     // data.result[0][0]
                "Pedidos":[...]   // data.result[0][0].Pedidos
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ]
}
```

Você pode obter o tamanho do array "Pedidos" da seguinte forma:

```
data.result[0][0]['Pedidos'].length;
```

Onde `'Pedidos'` poderia estar também em uma variável:

```
var x = 'Pedidos';
data.result[0][0][x].length;
```

Todo objeto JavaScript pode ter suas propriedades acessadas como se fosse um array associativo:

```
objeto.campo == objeto["campo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var comando = eval("data.result[0][0].Pedidos.length");
```

ou como preferir

```
var variavel = "pedidos";
var comando = eval("data.result[0][0]."+variavel+".length");
```